# Connecting to Oracle from Teradata

Tags: oracle, teradata, dblink

I have to run a report based on the Teradata tables but I need to extract a field from table residing in Oracle database. Can somebody please help me how I can create a DBLink between these two databases?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to access oracle database trough teradata?

Comment: Here's a link for you to connect to Teradata **from** Oracle (which uses DBLinks), if this is an option: https://community.oracle.com/thread/339454
Scroll all the way down.